# Why is Code 1 faster than Code 2?

Tags: python, performance

**Code 1:**

```
n = int(input())
ls = []
for x in range(n):
    ls += [(input())]
ls.sort(key = int)
for x in ls:
    print (x)
```

**Code 2:**

```
n = int(input())
ls = []
for x in range(n):
    ls += [int(input())]
ls.sort()
for x in ls:
    print (x)
```

These were my solutions to the HackerRank's "Big Sorting" problem:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/big-sorting

**Code 1 does not give time limit exceeded error while Code 2 does.**

**Why is Code 1 faster and than Code 2?**

Comment: You can trivially make the code more efficient by using `append` instead of `+=`. That said, this looks like an interesting question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is slower because you now need to convert the list of integers back to strings, while version 2 keeps the string versions, only converting to integers to sort.

Converting integers back to strings takes time too:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit("str(235739630407432043190819704398)", number=10**7)
2.4063552810002875
```

I strongly suspect that the values to sort included in some of the tests are both numerous and very, very large.

I'd not use *in-place extending* either. Use a list comprehension instead:

```
ls = [input() for x in range(n)]
```

Personally, I'd use iteration over `sys.stdin` to read faster than `input()` calls can; here *all loops* are delegated to optimised C code:

```
import sys
from itertools import islice

n = int(next(sys.stdin))
nums = sorted(map(str.strip, islice(sys.stdin, n)), key=int)
print(*nums, sep='\n')
```

(because the last line read from `stdin` has no newline you can't count on the newline being present on all lines, and then it's just easier and faster to strip).

Replacing `str.strip` with `int` will once more cause time-outs.